# How can I find out if a File is a file or directory if it does not exist?

Tags: java

`File.isFile()` and `File.isDirectory()` both return false not only when the `File` is not the specified type, but also when the `File` itself does not exist on the filesystem.  How can I determine whether the `File` represents a file or a directory when it does not exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, a specific path can represent both a directory and a file. Until there is either a directory or a file created at that path, the notion of it being for one or the other is invalid.

There is however a special case. If the path ends with a path separator ('/' on Unix-like systems, '\' on Windows and maybe something completely different on other systems), then at least on Unix-like systems the path cannot be that of a file. I do not know if this is valid for all systems though.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is like asking this:

> "How can I tell if this box contains a cat or a dog when it is empty?"

On the face of it, this question is nonsensical, and so is yours.  If a File is a path refers to a non-existent file system object (i.e. to "nothing") then asking whether that "nothing" >>is<< a file or a directory is meaningless.  It is obviously neither.

Specifically, at any instant in time all of the following predicates hold:

```
 file.exists() == false IMPLIES 
      file.isDirectory() == false AND file.isFile() == false

 file.isDirectory() == true OR file.isFile() == true IMPLIES 
      file.exists() == true

 file.isDirectory() == true IMPLIES 
      file.isFile() == false

 file.isFile() == true IMPLIES 
      file.isDirectory() == false
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't

The file must exists first in order to know what it **IS** ( I understand that if the file does not exist it IS nothing yet )

The javadoc says in both cases:

> *true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname **exists** and [...]*

A file that does not exists yet may be both potentially.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that you can't.  Part of the reason is that it just doesn't exist.  The rest of the reason has to do with the system-independence of Java.  Depending on what operating system you're running on, there isn't really a difference between a file and a directory.  In UNIX for example, everything is a file.  Pipes, directories, links -- they're all technically files.

As it stands, the abstract pathname referenced by the File object could be either one -- until you perform either `mkdir()` or `createNewFile()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Test File.exists() first.

Pseudo-Code (because I don't do Java :)  ):

```
If File.Exists()
{
    If File.isFile()
    {
        bIsFile = true;
    }elseif File.isFolder()
    {
        bIsFolder = true;
    }else
    {
        //Handle error condition here
    }
}else
{
    //It does not exist. Handle that here if you care to
}
```

Comment: But I want to know whether it's a file or a directory whether or *not* it exists...

Comment: If it doesn't exist, it's neither fish nor fowl - it's not anything.

Comment: EBGreen, I think you just won the prize for most complicated smiley/parentheses interaction ever! :o)

Comment: Emoticon palidrome for the win. :)

Comment: Hungarian notation, yuck :)

oh and .isDirectory() returns true only if .exists() returns true and the File is really a directory.

Comment: @Esko: No, not Hungarian, but MS's abortion of it arising from completely misunderstanding the principles espoused by the inventor.  But, yes, YUCK!