# Is checking for an extension an acceptable way to determine if given path is for a file or directory

Tags: java, file, directory

I need to check if a give path is a file or directory, if it is a file save a dummy text file inside its parent directory, if it is a directory the save the dummy text file inside it directly.

I am using `isDirectory()` and `isFile()` methods to check for the type.
What happens if the given path doesn't actually exists? It is impossible to determine its type.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279395/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-file-is-a-file-or-directory-if-it-does-not-exist) and it says you can't know. I was wondering if it is acceptable to determine the type based on whether it has an extension or not? Does that make sense?

Is there any other possible way to know?

Comment: You might want to tell us more about your actual use case. Both files without extensions and directories with extensions, or rather dots in their name are valid on most file systems. So figuring out whether a non-existing path is meant to be a file or a directory can only based on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you linked already answers your question:

> In general, a specific path can represent both a directory and a file.

You can name your folder `/foo.txt/` and it is still a folder. Only possibility would be to check if there is a `/` or `\` at the end of the path (which is also discussed at your link)

Comment: but it can also be a folder without the trailing `/` or ` \ `  right?

Comment: if there is a way to know for sure that there will always be a `/` or `\ ` on a folder you can use this method, otherwise you can't